# how can I track my android application is download?

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

> I am building an android application where I can know the number of
>   downloads done by the users of my android application.
>
> Is there any process. I had googled and has found it can be done by
>   Broadcasting. But how can I apply Broadcast method in my code.
>
> Please help!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you mean you want to track how many user downloaded your app and installed it ?

then its done automatically by playstore if you intend to publish app on google playstore you dont have to do anything.

**Update :**

if you want to track download by your self. then you can develop your own web service which will be called when app runs for first time.and database will record device id and you can get download statistics for your app.

for example Webservice could be like registerAppInstall(deviceId)

then you can count devices registered on db side to get statastics

Comment: @kitan thanks i had publish my app but I dont want to open my googleplaystore account to check the downloads. Is there alternative method to check this

Comment: there is no code playstore provides statistics to app publishers how many time the app is downloaded by user.

Comment: You mean to say that there is no way to check the download of app and show to my application itself